# cmd-f freezes the program and has unexpected inputs in mac os X

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, vim, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a mac os X. After certain point, cmd-f is taking a very long time in every programs. The program freezes so that I have to eventually force quit the program I tried cmd-f. Another cue is that I see unexpected inputs in the find box. The only thing I recall changing before getting this issue is that I was playing with vim in Terminal. Either it is because I may pressed a wrong shortkey in vim or I have created a .vimrc file? Yet, deleting .vimrc file did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Cmd-f or ctrl-f? You said one in your title, the other in your body text. Which programs exactly? Exactly what kind of unexpected input? What were you hoping cmd-f or ctrl-f was going to do?

Comment: @Spiff Hi, thank you for the notice. It is cmd-f. Actually turning the computer on and off solved the issue, while I still don't know what happened.

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve it. When you solve your own problem, you're encouraged to post your own Answer to your own Question, and then click the checkmark to accept your own Answer. That way the Question gets marked as resolved, and other people can learn the resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting the computer resolved the issue. I am still unsure what caused the bug, but I am closing the question as resolved.